# Typescript doesn't respect the "delete" operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I use the `delete` operator, Typescript doesn't seem to "know" that the property has been removed. For example:

```
interface HasName {
  name: string;
}

interface HasNoName {
  name: never;
}

function removeName(
  input: HasName,
): HasNoName {
  const output = {...input};
  delete output.name;
  return output; // This throws an error
}
```

Typescript rejects the function with this error:

```
 Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HasNoName'.
  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

To my way of thinking, by deleting the `name` property, Typescript should consider `output` to be compatible with `HasNoName`, yet this doesn't seem to be the case.

I can easily work around it, e.g. `const nameless = output as HasNoName; return nameless`. But I would like to know **WHY** this error occurs, and whether it's a bug or intentional?

Comment: My assumption would be that since the output is being constructed from the data of a HasName, typescript is associating the output also as a HasName.  But that's just an assumption

Comment: I believe this is because the type is inferred only when you assign a value

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the `delete` operator, but with the fact that the `return` statement will not "Cast" the output to the type of the return if it doesn't match (hasName != HasNoName), thinking that way you need to make an explicit cast and assume the risk, like that:

```
removeName(
    input: HasName,
  ): HasNoName {
    const output = {...input};
    delete output.name;
    return <HasNoName>output;
  }
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `delete` operator. Instead, use object destructuring:

```js
interface HasName {
  name: string;
}

interface HasNoName {
  name?: never;
}

function removeName(
  input: HasName,
): HasNoName {
  const { name: _, ...output } = input;
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Type 'LoDashStatic' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: I don't think my answer is related to LoDash by any means